# When mouse is moved open AppBar

Tags: c#

In creating a Windows App using C# how would I make an event when the mouse is moved anywhere in the page the AppBar is open(shown)?

This is what I have so far.

```
private void Page_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
appBar.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you hooked your event up in XAML?

For Example

```
<Page PointerMoved="Page_PointerMoved">
//Your Page
</Page>
```

Comment: Sorry, it just had said I have to wait 9minutes before marking as correct